# 'sharedApplication' is unavailable: not available on iOS (App Extension) for Segmentio/Analytics Pod

Tags: swift, cocoapods, analytics, segment-io

Running Xcode version 8.2.1, Swift 3, and Cocoapods version 1.1.1 and I can't for the life of me figure out how to resolve this issue. I need to use the analytics library but can't get past this error in the UIViewController+SEGScreen.m class:
[image]

Without forking, is there another solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly do you need to figure out? The API is not available when targeting iOS extensions. There is no solution but fixing the API. If this is an open source, the fix looks really simple (wrapping in a custom macro such `#ifdef TARGET_EXTENSION`). If not, time to use a properly written analytics framework, that takes into account all aspects of iOS development, not the most trivial ones only.

Comment: I need to figure out a workaround but it seems like the only way to use this SDK is through Cocoapods unless I'm missing something? Wouldn't the #ifdef get overwritten on pod install?

Comment: I've never forked before so I'm not quite sure how that works. Could you help me with that please? :)

Comment: Also, I just noticed you posted a comment on that issue. Thanks for the support!

Comment: In github, you click the fork button. Make the changes you want to the framework so they suit you. Then in your podfile, you specify `pod 'MyForkedFramework', :git => 'https://github.com/user/MyForkedFramework.git'`

Comment: Sorry to keep bugging you but when I forked the sdk, made my changes, and updated cocoapods, when i ran pod install it reverted my changes. This is what it looks like in my pod file. Does this look correct to you?

Comment: `   pod 'Analytics', :git => 'https://github.com/Chelsea-Pritchard/analytics-ios.git'`

Comment: Huh? You haven't pushed any of your changes. https://github.com/Chelsea-Pritchard/analytics-ios/commits/master